# Programmatically retrieve Application Pool Defaults

Tags: iis-7, powershell, application-pools

Using the IIS namespace, one can query the IIS Apppool settings, using:

`$pools = get-wmiobject -namespace "root/microsoftiisv2" -query 'select * from IIsApplicationPoolSetting'`

However, this only returns information about the existing application pools.

How can one query the current **application pool defaults**, the same that are retrieved from `Application Pools > Set Application Pool Defaults`. These values are different from the Default Application Pool (DefaultAppPool)

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started:

```
import-module webadministration
Get-WebConfiguration /system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults
```